# How to run multiple instances of the same Next JS app with different configs on same machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, environment-variables

I would like to run 2 instances of the NextJS app on the same machine with different configurations and ports

First instance is on port 3000, the second on port 3001, and this works fine with

`next dev`

`next dev -p 3001`

I have a couple of environment variables, which need to have different values per instance, and this works fine as well when they are not running up in parallel.

```
API_1=xyz
API_2=xyz
```

`next dev`

`API_1=xzy123 API_2=xyz123 next dev -p 3001`

The issue is, when I start both instances, environment variables from the last started instance are applied. I figure it that I should start each instance in a separate dist folder. So I tried to add dist folder name as env variable, but it doesn't work.

```
API_1=xyz
API_2=xyz
DIR=.next
```

```
next.config.js

module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    distDir: process.env.DIR
};
```

`next dev`

`DIR=.next-2 API_1=xzy123 API_2=xyz123 next dev -p 3001`

Comment: you can try is to use the cross-env package

Comment: Doesn't help. It seems that only variables used in next.config.js I can't override. Always original value from env file is taken.

Comment: Environment variables are set per environment. So you can't have two values for the same variable name in the same environment. So, use something other than environment variables. Maybe store the information in a config file and read it from the current working directory, which should differ between the two instances?

Comment: I have resolved my "challenge" by installing blitz. For more info check https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25764#discussioncomment-3417423

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it `next.config.js` using a environment variable. Ex:

```
{
  ...
  distDir: process.env.XYZ == 'true' ? 'dirA' : 'dirB',
}
```

And then in your `package.json` you create a script for each. Ex:

```
{
  ...
  dev: "next dev",
  dev2: "XYZ=true next dev"
}
```